# Append all data in a directory - Stata

Tags: stata

I would like to append all .dta data in a directory. The datasets have four common string characters "GTAH" in their names. I tried creating a list of all the data and saving it as a txt file, then looping and appending the datasets from the list. Some parts of my code work but got an error from the loop function. The code is used and the error message is below:

```
** set working directory
cd "C:\Data"

** list of all GTAH datasets in the directory
dir *GTAH*.dta 

 *dataset a list of all GTAH dataset and save list to GTAH_List.txt
! dir *GTAH*.dta /a-d /b >C:\Data\GTAH_List.txt

    
** Open GTAH_List as myfile and read the first line
file open myfile using "C:\Data\GTAH_List.txt", read
file read myfile line

**Save first dataset as master data and read next line for GTAH_List
use `line'
save GTAH_master_data, replace
file read myfile line

**Loop and append datasets from the GTAH_List (r(eof)==0 tells stata read all lines unlist the end of the list where r(eof)==1
while r(eof)==0 {
    append using 'line'
    file read myfile line
}
```

Error message -
*file 'line' not found
r(601)*;

Any advice or help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The immediate bug here is using the wrong quotation marks `'line'` around the macro name.  As your answer details, there is no need to get the list of filenames from your OS when Stata will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think may have found a solution here - https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1530135-append-all-dta-files-in-directory

From Bill Rising response - comment #6

```
cd "C:\Data"
clear
append using `: dir . files "*.dta"'
```

This worked for me (the data is quite large and still appending at the time of posting this answer).